# Can't load images in CardGroup from props in react.semantic-ui

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using the example from [this page](https://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card#card-example-card-props), in conjunction withe Card Group example loading from props. My props are hard coded as shown here:

```
import tellUsWhoImg  from './assets/images/matchScreen.PNG'

const items = [
    {
        image: './assets/images/matchScreen.PNG',
        header: 'tellUsWho',
        description: 'Applying Scala functional programming concepts to generate a set of ' +
        'JSON matches for every user to take our survey',
        meta: 'Match Generation Algorithm',
    },  
    {
        image: {tellUsWhoImg},
        header: 'tellUsWho',
        description: 'Applying Scala functional programming concepts to generate a set of ' +
        'JSON matches for every user to take our survey',
        meta: 'Match Generation Algorithm',
    }
 //etc....
]
```

and declaring my card group as the example shows:

```
const ProjectCardGroup = () => (
    <Container text style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
        <Card.Group items={items}/>
    </Container>
```

results in this:

[image: imgsFromProps]

If I hard code my cards declaratively, I can load the images no problem using the import statement but NOT the absolute path?:

```
<Container text style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
    <Card.Group>
       <Card>
       <Card.Content>
        <Image  size='medium' src={tellUsWhoImg} />
        <Card.Header>
            tellUsWho
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Meta>
            Match Generation Algorithm
        </Card.Meta>
        <Card.Description>
            Applying Scala functional programming concepts to generate a set of
            JSON matches for every user to take our survey
        </Card.Description>
    </Card.Content>
    </Card>
    <Card>
        <Card.Content>
            <Image  size='medium' src='./assets/images/matchScreen.PNG' />
            <Card.Header>
                nodeJS Distributed WebCrawler
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>
                nodeJS/Redis/EC2
            </Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>
                Utlizing redis as a centralized job queue installed via AWS Elasticache,
                able to spawn ec2 nodes and run multiple nodeJS worker instances to scour amazon to detect
                price discrepancies in books for trade-in value
            </Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
    </Card>
    </Card.Group>
<Container>
```

resulting in:

[image: hardCodeImgs]

Which leads me to THREE questions:

**1) Why does the format change when I try to load the images via props? (the grey header section)**

**2) Why does the image not load via props?**

**3) Why when the image is hardcoded does it not render with the same path to the image that is supplied in the import statement that DOES work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the format change when I try to load the images via props? (the grey header section)

Shorhand props generate following markup:

```
<Card>
   <Image src="..." />
   <Card.Content />
</Card>
```

While you wrap `Image` *inside* the `Card.Content` and this gives another styling result.

---

> Why does the image not load via props?

```
image: './assets/images/matchScreen.PNG',
```

I'm almost sure that this path is not valid and your web-server returns 404 error.

```
image: {tellUsWhoImg},
image: {tellUsWhoImg: tellUsWhoImg},
```

You should provide an object there, the second string illustrates a problem. The correct usage:

```
image: tellUsWhoImg,
```

> Why when the image is hardcoded does it not render with the same path to the image that is supplied in the import statement that DOES work?

Paths are diffefent:

- import path is relative to the directory of your JS file
- hardcoded path is relative to your www-root

Comment: thank you using `image: tellUsWhoImg` instead of the curly braces allowed me to load the image.